# Magento 2 setup:di:compile exclude folders

Tags: magento2, compiler, interceptor, setup-di-compile

Is it possible to exclude folders for a Magento 2 extension to be able to support Magento 2 compile command?

Currently `setup:di:compile` throws errors that parent classes not found as they are loaded with special custom "require_once like" function. I would like to make things work without change everything into Magento folder structure. (Most of the codes are not Magento specific, this is why I can't place everything into standard Magento directories.)

Any idea to make it work?

### UPDATE 06.10.2016.

I tracked down the whole compile process and there was only one trick what I found to exclude a folder in the extensions. It was the `test` folder in the module which should contain the tests...

What I tried:

- Interceptor for `ClassesScanner` class `getList` method: `beforeGetList`

`$this->classesScanner->addExcludePatterns(array(
    'anything' => array('/^' . preg_quote('pathToMagento2\app\code\Company\Module\libraries', '/') . '/')
));`

**Result**: libraries folder were skipped by the `Repositories code generation` task, but stuck in the `Application code generator` as that exclude not applied here.

### Possible solution

Intercept `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand` class's `getOperationsConfiguration` method -> `afterGetOperationsConfiguration` and modify the return values which contains these excludes and add our paths... But It wasn't possible to intercept as it is a private method...